# El atributo protected no funciona

Tags: php

Voy a desarrollar un sistema de tamaño medio que tendrá varios registros, ediciones y exclusiones. Usaré el modo procedimental. Crearé un archivo llamado metodosClass.php. Para que el archivo no sea demasiado pesado y para una mejor organización, también crearé otras clases. Son ellas:

```
cadastrarClass.php
editarClass.php
excluirClass.php
visualizarClass.php
```

La estructura se verá así:

**cadastrar.php**

```
<?php
include("includes/classes.php");
$metodos = new metodosClass();
if($_POST["Submit"] == "Cadastrar")
{
   $produto = $_POST["Produto"];
   echo $metodos->cadastrar($produto);
}
```

**includes/classes.php**

```
include("classes/conectarClass.php");
include("classes/cadastrarClass.php");
include("classes/sairClass.php");
include("classes/metodosClass.php");
include("classes/visualizarClass.php");
include("classes/excluirClass.php");
include("classes/editarClass.php");
```

**classes/metodosClass.php**

```
<?php
class metodosClass
{
protected $conexao;
  /**
  * Classe construtor
  */
  public function __construct()
  {
     $conectar = new conectaClass();
     $this->conexao = $conectar->conectar();
     return $this->conexao;
  }

  protected function codificar($key)
  {
     $codificar = md5($key);
     return $codificar;
  }

 public function cadastrar($produtos)
  {
     $c = new cadastrarClass();
     $c->cadastrar($produtos);
  }
}
```

**classes/cadastrarClass.php**

```
<?php
class cadastrarClass
{
protected $conexao;
  /**
  * Classe construtor
  */
  public function __construct()
  {
     $conectar = new conectaClass();
     $this->conexao = $conectar->conectar();
     return $this->conexao;
  }
public function cadastrar($produto)
  {
    mysqli_query($this->conexao,"INSERT INTO model_produtos(Produtos) 
                                 VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$produto)."');");
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($this->conexao) > 0)
    {
      $c = new metodosClass();
      $codificar = $c->codificar(mysqli_insert_id($this->conexao));
      mysqli_query($this->conexao,"UPDATE model_produtos
                                   SET IdCodProdutos = '".$codificar."'
                                   WHERE IdProdutos = '".mysqli_insert_id($this->conexao)."';");
      $_SESSION["Sucesso"] = time() + 3;
      return "<script>window.location.href='".$this->caminhoAbsoluto."';</script>";
    }
  }
}
```

El problema es que el método del codificar($key), que está protegido, no funciona, solo cuando se hace público. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Feliz Navidad

Perdón por mi español.

Comment: `protected` hace que solo pueda acceder a ese método la propia clase que lo define o una clase que *herede* de ella. No veo que tu clase `cadastrarClass` herede de `metodosClass`, así que obviamente no tiene acceso al método

Comment: Hola Benito. Lo puse así: `class cadastrarClass extends metodosClass`, pero dio el siguiente error:
Error fatal: Error no detectado: No se encontró la clase 'metodosClass'. Así que puse el include: `include (" methodsClass.php ");`, en el archivo classes / cadastrarClass.php, da otro error:
`Error fatal: no se puede declarar classmethodsClass`. Porque en el archivo cadastrar.php ya hago esta llamada.

Comment: Solución fácil, hazlo `public`. Es un método que vas a llamar desde otras clases, lo lógico sería que fuese público ya que no veo que la herencia en este caso sea realmente necesaria o útil. Por cierto, para extender clases en php no usas el `include`, necesitas indicarle la clase con `use \carpeta\clase`, si usas `include` estarás intentando *meter* la otra clase dentro de esta...